# kineticjs Text change

Tags: javascript, node.js, kineticjs

I'm having the following problem
I am using kinetics and have drawn a Text shape with a text and color.
I have a normal input field on the same page and want to use the on change event of this object to call a js function that will update the text property of the Text Shape and automatically redraw it so the entered text is shown in the stage-layer
I am using node, express and jade

Answer (score 2):

Briefly,

- listen for changes in your text input
- change the kinetic text with setText

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/62Wjc/

```
document.getElementById("myHtmlTextInput").addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    text.setText(this.value);
    layer.draw();
},false);
```